# Interface as fields in struct and interface calls methods which takes input as same struct

Tags: go, methods, struct, interface, field

In my case, "RequestHandlerProxy" is a structure which has field as interface "IAdapter" and interface has may methods to be called that method has input as structure "RequestHandlerProxy". Please help me how to work with this? How can I define values to struct "RequestHandlerProxy" and pass through?

Below is my structure and methods of interface: Interface "IAdapter" is in file "adapters"

```
type RequestHandlerProxy struct {
    TestMode       bool
    coreInstanceId string
    adapter        adapters.IAdapter
    coreProxy      adapterif.CoreProxy
}

func NewRequestHandlerProxy(coreInstanceId string, iadapter adapters.IAdapter, cProxy adapterif.CoreProxy) *RequestHandlerProxy {
    var proxy RequestHandlerProxy
    proxy.coreInstanceId = coreInstanceId
    proxy.adapter = iadapter
    proxy.coreProxy = cProxy
    return &proxy
}

func (rhp *RequestHandlerProxy) Adapter_descriptor() (*empty.Empty, error) {
    return new(empty.Empty), nil    
}

func (rhp *RequestHandlerProxy) Device_types() (*voltha.DeviceTypes, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

func (rhp *RequestHandlerProxy) Health() (*voltha.HealthStatus, error) {    
    return nil, nil
}
```

Below is my interface in adapters file:

```
type IAdapter interface {
    Adapter_descriptor() error
    Device_types() (*voltha.DeviceTypes, error)
    Health() (*voltha.HealthStatus, error)
}
```

Comment: Please use go fmt to format your code and then you want to take the Go tour https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Comment: If your need help with basics of the language please come up with a *minimal* example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am making UT cases so there I couldn't use fmt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is a bit difficult to follow (incomplete and its purpose unclear) so here is a simplified example which will hopefully answer your question. Note that from the question title I'm assuming that the fact that `RequestHandlerProxy` implements the interface `IAdapter` is confusing you; that is probably irrelevant (it may be that there are other functions that accept an `IAdapter` where it would make sense to pass in a `RequestHandlerProxy` or your own implementation of `IAdapter` such as `adaptImpl` below).

I have simplified `IAdapter` to contain a single function and put everything in one file. To expand this to work in your example you will need to implement all three functions (`Adapter_descriptor()`,`Device_types()` & `Health()`). Code can be run in the [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1um7fEqAEne) (if this does not answer your question perhaps you can modify that code to provide a simplified example of your issue).

```
package main
import "errors"

// IAdapter - Reduced to one function to make this simple
type IAdapter interface {
    Adapter_descriptor() error
}

/// NewRequestHandlerProxy - Simplified version of the New function
func NewRequestHandlerProxy(iadapter IAdapter) {
    return // code removed to make example simple
}

// adaptImpl - Implements the IAdapter interface
type adaptImpl struct {
    isError bool // example only
}

// Adapter_descriptor - Implement the function specified in the interface
func (a adaptImpl) Adapter_descriptor() error {
    if a.IsError {
        return errors.New("An error happened")
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    // Create an adaptImpl which implements IAdapter 
    x := adaptImpl{isError: true}
    NewRequestHandlerProxy(x)
}
```

Comment: The above example you have defined is very clear and am aware of this. The way to call method is by passing values to struct and using struct we can call methods that is what you have done. But in my case it's a bit difficult. Sine I am making UT for the code I couldn't modify the above source code. Just trying to pass through it.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly you need to call ```NewRequestHandlerProxy``` without modifying any of the above code? If thats the case then my example stands; you will need to pass in something that implements ```IAdapter```; this may be something you create yourself (the point of an interface is that you can pass in anything that implements the interface) or using an existing struct provided elsewhere (note that you cannot use ```RequestHandlerProxy``` itself because that would be recursive). As things stand you have not provided enough information to provide a more detailed response.

Comment: Did a quick search - your code is from the voltha package (would have been helpful to state that). That being the case I'd refer you to an example from that package; https://github.com/opencord/voltha-openolt-adapter/blob/master/adaptercore/openolt.go implements the IAdapter interface.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a great example on the link you have provided. The thing is we need to create a dummy struct on other side just by defining then using the values we can call the function. Very much helpful. Thanks again.